# Convert boolean numpy array to pillow image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I'm currently working with image processing in python using the scikit-image library. I'm trying to make a binary image using sauvola thresholding with the following code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage.filters import threshold_sauvola

im = Image.open("test.jpg")
pix = numpy.array(im)
img = rgb2gray(pix)

window_size = 25
thresh_sauvola = threshold_sauvola(img, window_size=window_size)
binary_sauvola = img > thresh_sauvola
```

Which gives the following result:
[image]

the output is a numpy array with data type of this image is a bool

```
[[ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 ...
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True ...  True  True  True]]
```

The problem is that I need to convert this array back to a PIL image using the following line of code:

```
image = Image.fromarray(binary_sauvola)
```

which makes the image look like this:

[image]

I also tried to change the data type from bool to uint8 but then I'll get the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'mask'
```

So far I haven't found a solution to get a PIL image which looks like the result of the thresholding.

Comment: "I also tried to change the data type from bool to uint8" please show the attempt. It clearly didn't use `view` or `astype`, so really not sure what you did.

Comment: I tried the following line to change the dtype to uint8
`image = Image.fromarray(binary_sauvola.astype('uint8'))`

Comment: Then show the stack trace. That error seems strange. Please edit the question. Don't put cow and errors into comments if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update

This bug has now been solved in Pillow==6.2.0. The link to the issue on GitHub is [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3109).

If you cannot update to the new version of Pillow, please see below.

---

PIL's `Image.fromarray` function has a bug with mode '1' images. [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/b09216123cca86e9b9cf889bfd3c5cec) demonstrates the bug, and shows a few workarounds. Here are the best two workarounds:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# The standard work-around: first convert to greyscale 
def img_grey(data):
    return Image.fromarray(data * 255, mode='L').convert('1')

# Use .frombytes instead of .fromarray. 
# This is >2x faster than img_grey
def img_frombytes(data):
    size = data.shape[::-1]
    databytes = np.packbits(data, axis=1)
    return Image.frombytes(mode='1', size=size, data=databytes)
```

Also see [Error Converting PIL B&W images to Numpy Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761645/error-converting-pil-bw-images-to-numpy-arrays).

Comment: img_grey doesn't give me the right result, but img_frombytes does. Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @R.hagens My pleasure! It's interesting that `img_grey` misbehaves for you. I'm not sure why that happens, I did my research on this topic almost a year ago, and I forget the fine details. But I prefer `img_frombytes`, since I wrote it. :)

Comment: well if you're interested, img_grey gave me the following result https://imgur.com/a/VC3yqs4

Comment: @R.hagens Thanks. It's essentially the same bug, but I'll have to think about why it still happens despite the greyscale conversion that `img_grey` does.

Comment: This issue has been solved in the latest pillow==6.2.0. The link to the issue on github: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3109

Answer (score 2):

This option might was not available 2018 but currently

```
from skimage.io._plugins.pil_plugin import ndarray_to_pil, pil_to_ndarray
ndarray_to_pil(some_binary_image).convert("1")
```

seems to do the trick.