# How to save image as binary compressed .tiff python?

Tags: python, tiff

Is there any library to save images in binary (1bit per pixel) .tiff compressed file?
opencv and pillow cannot do that

Comment: do you find any solution for your problem ?

Comment: @beesleep I haven't found a solution so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I just found a way to do it with Pillow, but some tweaks are needed because of [some bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134667/5547936).

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, TiffImagePlugin

filepath = '/some/file/path.tif'
# generate a 1bit image
ar = np.random.rand(50, 50) > 0.5
arr_2 = np.repeat(np.repeat(ar, 10, axis=0), 10, axis=1)

# save it t
size = mask.shape[::-1]
databytes = np.packbits(mask, axis=1)
mask = Image.frombytes(mode='1', size=size, data=databytes)
TiffImagePlugin.WRITE_LIBTIFF = True
mask.save(filepath, compression='packbits')
TiffImagePlugin.WRITE_LIBTIFF = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using libtiff.

Install using `pip install libtiff`

Comment: can you provide exact way to save? something like `libtiff.save_image(fname, format='rle')` - I am unsure if it's possible with this library