# Understanding different behaviors of PyTorch on CPU/GPU when typecasting boolean to float

Tags: numpy, pytorch, python-imaging-library

I load this binary mask to a PyTorch tensor and I observe different behavior based on whether I load it on CPU or GPU. Is this behavior expected? Where can I learn more about it?

```
In [1]: from PIL import Image; import torch; import numpy as np

In [2]: mask = torch.from_numpy(np.array(Image.open('Black_Footed_Albatross_0002_55.png')))

In [3]: mask.dtype
Out[3]: torch.bool

In [4]: mask.float().unique()
Out[4]: tensor([  0., 255.])

In [5]: mask.to('cuda').float().unique()
Out[5]: tensor([-1.,  0.], device='cuda:0')
```

[image]

Comment: PIL Image seems to return a `bool` view of a `uint8` array, the array is not converted to `bool`. This is reproducible with `a = np.array([255, 128, 64, 32, 1, 0], dtype=np.uint8).view(np.bool_); b = torch.from_numpy(a); b.float()` outputs `tensor([255., 128.,  64.,  32.,   1.,   0.])`.  With `cuda` the memory is interpreted as `int8` (signed two's complement) and converted, `b.to('cuda').float()` outputs `tensor([  -1., -128.,   64.,   32.,    1.,    0.], device='cuda:0')`. No bug, just interesting behaviour when converting a `np.view` with `torch.from_numpy`.

Comment: After reconsideration, I'm no longer sure if the `cuda` behavior is intentional and justified, at least it's surprising and undocumented as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelSzczesny. Interesting, I didn't know the discrepancy in PIL's behavior. Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134468/convert-boolean-numpy-array-to-pillow-image and  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/54789